# Proving an inequality using AM/HM or other inequalities

Tags: inequality, triangles, a.m.-g.m.-inequality

> Let x, y, z be real positive numbers, which are generated from the Ravi transformation of a triangle. Use AM-HM or any other inequality
> to prove that $$\sqrt{x^2 + y (2 x + 2 z) + 2 y^2 + z^2}<2x+2y$$

The Ravi transformation of a triangle is shown by the following illustration:

[image]

Take each side and form it as $D=x+y$, $E=y+x$ and $F=z+x$.

My take:
$$\sqrt{x^2 + y (2 x + 2 z) + 2 y^2 + z^2}<2x+2y$$

$$x^2 + y (2 x + 2 z) + 2 y^2 + z^2<4(x+y)^2$$

$$-3 x^2 - 6 x y - 2 y^2 + 2 y z + z^2<0$$

Reciprocal:

$$\frac1{z^2-3 x^2 - 2 y^2 + 2 y z - 6 x y}>0$$

Assuming, $z^2-3 x^2 - 2 y^2\leq0$, then we need only to prove that $$z^2-3 x^2 - 2 y^2<2 y z - 6 x y$$

Hence,
$$\frac{z^2-3 x^2 - 2 y^2}{y}<0<2z-6y$$

So if we can prove that $z^2-3 x^2 - 2 y^2\leq0$ holds, then the original inequality holds too.

However how can this be shown ?

Comment: Please include details about what is the ravi transform of a triangle.

Comment: @coffeemath, I think that$x+y,y+z,z+x$ are 3 sides of a triangle

Comment: Your inequality equal with $3b^2 \geq a^2$ which is not always true

Comment: @Luthier415Hz, are there any conditions for the triangle?

Comment: @LụcTrườngPhát OP corrected. No conditions for the triangle, it can be isosceles or right triangle or any other form

Comment: If there are no conditions on the triangle, then $x, y, z$ could be arbitrary positive reals, which means the inequality doesn't always hold (say take $z$ large enough).

Comment: @Macavity thnks!

Comment: Perhaps if right hand side was 2x + 2z instead of 2x+2y it could be true. The left hand side is the hypothenuse (z+x) if (x+y) and (z+y) are cathetes in a right triangle. But then I suspect the cosine theorem would be more fruitful.